# How to store different date precisions in one PostgreSQL column

Tags: postgresql, date, database-design, postgresql-9.1

I have different date types for some single events.

They can built up like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

or

```
YYYY-MM
```

or

```
YYYY
```

I want to store the data in one column. How do I have to set up my column definitions for this purpose.

**EDIT**

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE events (event date);

INSERT INTO events (event) VALUES ('2003-12-12');
```

ok

```
INSERT INTO events (event) VALUES ('2003');
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "2003"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO events (event) VALUES ('2003');
```

I'm using postgres 9.1

Answer (score 1):

If this is for events, look into the timestamp or date range types. You could then store the relevant range (begin to end) as you need.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

```
denis=# select '[2014-01-01,2015-01-01)'::daterange;
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2014-01-01,2015-01-01)
(1 row)

denis=# select '[2014-01-01,2014-02-01)'::daterange;
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2014-01-01,2014-02-01)
(1 row)

denis=# select '[2014-01-01,2014-01-02)'::daterange;
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2014-01-01,2014-01-02)
(1 row)

denis=# select daterange('2014-01-01'::date, ('2014-01-01'::date + '1 year'::interval)::date);
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2014-01-01,2015-01-01)
(1 row)
```

Comment: I've edited my question. I want to store single events with different precisions. I don't know if this is really possible, because the date type is defined strictly.

Comment: @StefanB.: in the examples I gave, you're storing single events with different precisions. The first three define a date range that spans a year, a month and a day from the start date respectively. They then allow you to check for overlaps and such if you ever need to — something a plain date or (worse) a varchar will not. To simplify input, you could create a function(_input date, _duration interval) that returns the appropriate daterange using the last example I added.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1, which does not support the daterange type. Your answer is nice, sorry for being so slow!

Comment: Seriously consider upgrading, if you can. 9.2 and 9.3 brings range types, json, fdw, index-only scans, and replication-related stuff on top of other enhancements. Else, the better/future-proof way to do what you want is to use two columns: two dates (start/end date) or a date and an interval (start date/duration).

Comment: How would you query the events which occurred at any day in February 2014? I'm working on natural hazards and sometimes there is only the information that a landslide occurred in a distinct month.

Comment: You'd query it using the daterange operators, e.g. `select * from events where evt_date @> '2014-02-01'::date`, or `select * from events where evt_date && '[2014-02-01,2014-03-01)'::daterange`, or `select * from events where evt_date <@ '[2014-02-01,2014-03-01)'::daterange`. The first would show daily, monthly and yearly events that include the 1st of february. The second would show daily, monthly and yearly events that intersect with the month of february 2014. The third would show daily and monthly events that are included in february 2014 events.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, instead of  "date" datatype use column type as varchar() , then u can store the different type of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to store something like this is e.g. using a `varchar` column which stores a partial date.

You can add a check constraint that would valid complete dates for correctness (using the `to_date()` function).

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE events 
(
   event varchar(10) not null,
   constraint chk_date check 
       (case  
           when length(event) = 4 then event::integer > 0  -- must be number
           when length(event) = 7 then concat(event,'-01')::date is not null -- make sure it's a valid month
           when length(event) = 10 then event::date is not null  -- make sure it's valid date
           else false 
        end
       )
);
```

The check constraint ensures that you can't insert invalid dates, not even partially (e.g. `'2013-17'`).

The validity check can only be done using a cast based on the ISO date format because `to_date('2013-17-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` will be converted to `2014-05-03`

Comment: But this isn't going to perform so great when OP starts to run date-based queries on it. :-(

Comment: @AHWNN: I want to use your constraint for a column which I have added after creating the table and inserting the data. I can't set the constraint because there are no values in the column. Is there a way that the constraint only looks for existing entries?